# Timestamp range to hours Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it a way to split timestamp range to hours ?

FROM:

| Person | start | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2019-01-01 12:15:00 | 2019-01-01 14:25:00 |

TO:

| Person | start | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2019-01-01 12:15:00 | 2019-01-01 13:00:00 |
| Tom | 2019-01-01 13:00:00 | 2019-01-01 14:00:00 |
| Tom | 2019-01-01 14:00:00 | 2019-01-01 14:25:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the ranges between `start.floor('h')` and `stop.ceil('h')` with `hour frequency` using [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), then return start, range from second to second last, and stop, it'll give a list, so `explode` it, assign stop to this range by shifting it by -1, and finally assign start to the range, and `dropna` rows (this na will appear due to the effect of shift, and is not required.)

```py
def getRange(row):
    rang = pd.date_range(row['start'].floor('h'), row['stop'].ceil('h'), freq='h')
    return [row['start']] + rang.to_list()[1:-1] + [row['stop']]


df =(df.assign(range=df.apply(getRange, axis=1))
.drop(columns=['start', 'stop'])
.explode('range')
  )
df = df.assign(stop=df['range'].shift(-1)).dropna().rename(columns={'range':'start'})
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
  Person               start                stop
0    Tom 2019-01-01 12:15:00 2019-01-01 13:00:00
0    Tom 2019-01-01 13:00:00 2019-01-01 14:00:00
0    Tom 2019-01-01 14:00:00 2019-01-01 14:25:00
```

Comment: nice answer +1 but don't assign anything to `range` function use any variable instead it will create many problem further

Comment: @AnuragDabas, Thanks for pointing dude, I'm the one who always suggests not to use built-in as variable name, and  today, I myself ended up doing that, Lol